# Pandas: Drop rows from a dataframe where dictionary stores row information

Tags: performance, query-optimization

I have a dataframe with personID and tickets they had booked. A person can book many tickets. I want to drop some persons and ticket combinations from the dataframe. I have the combinations in a dictionary. Following is the current version of my working code. I want to improve the compute time of this process as this is a large dataframe with millions of rows.

```
---------------------
| personID | ticket |
|----------|--------|
| 1        |  A     |
| 1        |  B     |
| 1        |  C     |
| 1        |  D     |
| 2        |  A     |
| 2        |  B     |
| 2        |  C     |
| 3        |  A     |
| 3        |  B     |
| 3        |  C     |
| 3        |  D     |
---------------------

p_dict = {1: ['A', 'D'], 3: ['B', 'C']}

for per, tick in p_dict.items():
    idxs = data[(data.personID == per) & (data.ticket.isin(tick))].index
    indices = np.append(indices, idxs)

data = data.drop(indices)
```

Using a dictionary of lists, I was able to get a bit of a speed-up rather than indexing multiple times per person and ticket (17mins to 6mins). Is there other optimizations that I could do?